# Print blank rows in the table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="obj1 in jsondata">
     <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
     <td>{{obj1.Subject_ID}}</td>
     <td>{{obj1.Credit}}</td>
 </tr>
 /********print blank row like following depends on jsondata length*****************/  
 <tr ng-repeat="obj1 in jsondata.length">
  <td colspan="3">&nsbp;<td>   
 </tr>
/******************************/
</table>
```

Suppose 
`jsondata.length` length is `7` then print 3 blank rows, else if  `jsondata.length` length is `8` then print 2 blank rows else if `jsondata.length` length is `10` or more then no blank row

How to do this using ng-repeat or in any other easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary Array with length 10. Based on your `jsonData` length display blank `td`

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj1 in jsondata">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{obj1.Subject_ID}}</td>
      <td>{{obj1.Credit}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="(temp.length >= jsondata.length)" ng-repeat="key in temp | limitTo: (jsondata.length - temp.length) track by $index">
      <td colspan="3">blank
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3lrjLSJMXVCct26PseWk?p=preview)**

Comment: yes it works fine  I tried same but some syntax mistakes  thanks

Comment: Looks like  blank rows are still created if the jsondata.length is more than 10.

Comment: @suzo Sorry. I have added that condition. Please have a look at updated answer

Comment: @Nagaveer Gowda more than 10 condition not work.  pls create demo